# Elman neural network Learn multiple-series series

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I start with neural networks, and I would like to know how I can do to have several input lists as an example of learning. In the documentation the example presented is the following :

```
[X,T] = simpleseries_dataset;
net = elmannet(1:2,10);
[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts] = preparets(net,X,T);
net = train(net,Xs,Ts,Xi,Ai);
view(net)
Y = net(Xs,Xi,Ai);
perf = perform(net,Ts,Y)
```

where Xs and Ts are the input and the target, if i have serval series, should i repeat the learning for each series? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use cell arrays of arrays. For example, if you have two series: `x1_1,x1_2,x1_3,...` and `x2_1,x2_2,x2_3,...`, the cell aray should be `{[x1_1,x2_1],[x1_2,x2_2],[x1_3,x2_3],...}`. If the series have different lengths, then the shorter series should be padded with NaNs. The [`catsamples`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/catsamples.html) function can be used to simplify the code:

```
[X,T] = simpleseries_dataset;
x1= X(1:30); t1= T(1:30); % first subsequence
x2= X(50:75); t2= T(50:75); % second subsequence
Xm = catsamples(x1,x2,'pad'); % concatenate to the cell array
Tm = catsamples(t1,t2,'pad'); % padding whith NaNs 
net = elmannet(1:2,10);
[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts] = preparets(net,Xm,Tm);
net = train(net,Xs,Ts,Xi,Ai);
Y = net(Xs,Xi,Ai);
perf = perform(net,Ts,Y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in my case my two series are of the form :  (x1_1,y1_1),(x1_2,y1_2),(x1_3,y1_3)....(x1_N,y1_N) and (x2_1,y2_1),(x2_2,y2_2),(x2_3,y2_3)....(x2_N,y2_N)

Comment: In this case (the series are of the same size), you don't need to pad the cell arrays: `Xm = catsamples(x1,x2); Ym = catsamples(y1,y2);`

Comment: No , sorry i think that I did not  explain my question well, I want to use a multiple time series, It is a form of several trajectories, (x1,y1) should be used to predict (x'1,y'1) and (x2,y2) should be used to predict (x'2,y'2)